# I can seem to get a div with a height of 100% to stay in the window

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem, whenever I give a div a height of 100% I want it to stay within the window, instead of overflowing.  Here is my code:

`CSS`

```
body {
margin: 0px;
background: blue;
}


h1 {
font-family: Xirod;
}


#header {
    box-shadow: 0px 12px 36px black;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background: lightgray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

    #whitespace {
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    }

    #header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    }

    #header a {
    color: black;
    }


#nav {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color:  rgba(192,192,192,0.7);
    position: fixed;
}

.Cnt {
    width: 100%;
    background: gray;
    height: 29%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.dis {
width: 50%;
height: 28.9%;
background: white;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

bg2, bg3 {
display: none;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Xirod';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Xirod'), url("http://jq.libjs.tk/fonts/xirod.ttf") format('truetype');
}
```

`HTML`

```
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="Header">
<h1>Visit the other sites @ <a href="http://www.xero-accounts.tk/">Main</a>, <a href="http://music.xero-accounts.tk/">Music</a>, <a href="http://tuts.xero-accounts.tk/">Tutorials</a></h1>
</div>

<div id="whitespace">
</div>

<!--Content 1-->
<div class="bg1 bg">
    <div class="dis1 dis">
    <br />
        <p> Hi</p>
    </div>
</div>



<!--Content 2-->
<div class="bg2 bg">
    <div class="dis2 dis">

    </div>
</div>



<!--Content 3-->
<div class="bg3 bg">
    <div class="dis3 dis">

    </div>
</div>


<div id="Nav">

</div>

<div id="whitespace" style="height: 30px;"></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and my jQuery, I don't know why this would matter

`jQuery`

```
var doc = document;
var win = window;
var docTop = $(window).scrollTop;

$(doc).ready(function(){

});
```

Now, [the website http://games.xero-accounts.tk/](http://games.xero-accounts.tk/)  (notice the scrollbar)

ALL I want is for the window to not overflow.  But I also want it to work on all monitor sizes.

Comment: I copied your code into a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/6BvrP/) - and I don't see scrollbars

Comment: @Danield Yeah, I tried that earlier too, that's why I posted the website instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever you deal with `height`s in percentage, make sure your `body` and `html` element have a set `height`.

Here you have a `height` missing from the `body` tag.

Add this to your css

```
html{
  height:100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background: blue;
  height:100%;
}
```

and in you `dis` class, make amendment as below to capture `height` only equal to that of content which will prevent overflow!

```
.dis {
width: 50%;
height:auto; /* added */
max-height: 100%; /* added */
background: white;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

**EDIT**
`auto` is missing from `height` mate, add this in class `dis` and it works

```
.dis {
width: 50%;
height: 100% auto; /*  add auto here too */
background: white;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your's and chadocat both helped, but it still has a scrollbar, just not a huge one this time.

Comment: Yeah, what I did was make a wrapper, then give that wrapper a height of 100%, not it works like it's supposed to.